# Spark driver using exorbitant amounts of memory

Tags: python, apache-spark

I'm trying to run a structured spark query which takes as input a kafka stream of user/ai message pairs and writes each pair that belong to a distinct conversation to a distinct delta table in s3. I chose this architecture so that it's relatively fast to query the entire history for a single conversation. When I run this on a spark-operator on eks, it uses absolutely insane amounts of memory (for a single conversation ~4GB, if I randomize the conversation id and stream one pair every 2 seconds it OOMs 5GB). I must be doing something horribly wrong.

Here's my query code:

```py
TABLE_NAME = "turn_history"


def write_to_s3(spark: SparkSession, s3_path: str, batch_df: DataFrame, _: int) -> None:
    # This function is called for each micro-batch
    # Loop through unique conversation_ids in the batch
    for conversation_id in (
        batch_df.select("conversation_id", "user_id").distinct().limit(100).collect()
    ):
        cid = conversation_id.conversation_id
        uid = conversation_id.user_id

        # Filter messages for the current conversation_id
        filtered_df = batch_df.filter(
            (f.col("conversation_id") == cid) & (f.col("user_id") == uid)
        ).alias("filtered_df")

        # Define dynamic path for the current conversation_id and window
        path = path_from_ids(s3_path, cid, uid)

        # could do this w/ sql but it's a bit more complex
        # because of the schema
        if not DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(spark, path):
            filtered_df.write.format("delta").option("path", path).saveAsTable(
                TABLE_NAME
            )
            return
        delta_table = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, path)
        delta_table.alias("turns").merge(
            filtered_df.alias("newTurns"),
            "turns.turn_id = newTurns.turn_id",
        ).whenNotMatchedInsertAll().execute()

def run_query() -> None:
    config = get_config()
    spark = get_spark_session(
        access_key=config.aws_access_key_id,
        secret_key=config.aws_secret_access_key,
    )

    logger.warning("Monitoring Kafka topic: %s", config.topic_name)
    # Define Kafka source
    kafka_source = (
        spark.readStream.format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", config.kafka_bootstrap_servers)
        .option("subscribe", config.topic_name)
        .load()
    )

    data = kafka_source.select(
        from_avro(f.col("value"), UserMessagePair.avro_schema()).alias("message")
    ).select("message.*")
    # run_sql_upsert(config.db_connection_str, data)

    # Use foreachBatch to apply the custom write function
    query = data.writeStream.trigger(processingTime="30 seconds").foreachBatch(
        partial(write_to_s3, spark, config.s3_path)
    )
    query.start()
    spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_query()
```